# which rule from routing table is used for given hosname/IP?

Tags: linux, routing

I have to work with obsolete vpn, and when I start it, it creates a lot of entries in routing table. Is there an automated way how to tell say "hostname youtube.com upon this request will be routed using rule on line 10"? I'd like to avoid calculating it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Routing deals with IP addresses exclusively. Because `youtube.com` can resolve to anything (even in subsequent calls) and also multiple IP addresses, a statement like “youtube.com is routed via 1.2.3.4” is not possible.

However, with a single IP address and iproute2, you can get query the routing table:

```
$ ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.2.1 dev br0 src 192.168.2.5 uid 1001
    cache
$ ip route get 100.64.0.1
100.64.0.1 dev wg0 src 100.64.0.2 uid 1001
    cache
```